# Getting individual colors from a color map in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

If you have a [Colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) `cmap`, for example:

```
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Spectral')
```

How can you get a particular colour out of it between 0 and 1, where 0 is the first colour in the map and 1 is the last colour in the map?

Ideally, I would be able to get the middle colour in the map by doing:

```
>>> do_some_magic(cmap, 0.5) # Return an RGBA tuple
(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 406, accepted):

You can do this with the code below, and the code in your question was actually very close to what you needed, all you have to do is call the `cmap` object you have.

```
import matplotlib

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Spectral')

rgba = cmap(0.5)
print(rgba) # (0.99807766255210428, 0.99923106502084169, 0.74602077638401709, 1.0)
```

For values outside of the range [0.0, 1.0] it will return the under and over colour (respectively). This, by default, is the minimum and maximum colour within the range (so 0.0 and 1.0). This default can be changed with `cmap.set_under()` and `cmap.set_over()`.

For "special" numbers such as `np.nan` and `np.inf` the default is to use the 0.0 value, this can be changed using `cmap.set_bad()` similarly to under and over as above.

Finally it may be necessary for you to normalize your data such that it conforms to the range `[0.0, 1.0]`. This can be done using [`matplotlib.colors.Normalize`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) simply as shown in the small example below where the arguments `vmin` and `vmax` describe what numbers should be mapped to 0.0 and 1.0 respectively.

```
import matplotlib

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=10.0, vmax=20.0)

print(norm(15.0)) # 0.5
```

A logarithmic normaliser ([matplotlib.colors.LogNorm](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LogNorm)) is also available for data ranges with a large range of values.

*(Thanks to both [Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington) and [tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell) for suggestions on how to improve the answer.)*

Comment: Actually, for values less than 0 or more than 1 it will return the "over" or "under" color. By default it's the color at the bottom/top of the colormap, but that's changable.  For example:  `cmap.set_under('red'); print cmap(0.0), cmap(-0.01)`

Comment: Hi @Joe, thanks for the correction, I've modified my answer :)

Comment: There is also `set_bad` which define what in does for `np.nan` and `np.inf` iirc.  You should mention the `Normalize` methods here as well.

Comment: @tcaswell thanks for the suggestions, have added them as well as an example of `matplotlib.colors.Normalize`.

Comment: Very useful information and why on earth is it impossible to find this in the documentation!?!

Comment: when I use default range, and I tried values above 1, it does not return a single "over" number, rather, the value changes with my input. I'm using matplotlib 2.0.0

Comment: If this isn't working for anyone, and you see `module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'cm'`, try replacing the first two lines with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Spectral')`

Comment: Does normalize have an equivalent to `set_bad`?

Comment: @Pengyao in my version of matplotlib the behavior depends on whether the input is an integer or a float. In the answer, a float is used. When specifying integers, it's different. Consult  the section `_call_(self, X, ...)` in `help(cmap)` to get an explanation: "For floats, X should be in the interval ``[0.0, 1.0]`` to return the RGBA values ``X*100`` percent along the Colormap line. For integers, X should be in the interval ``[0, Colormap.N)`` to return RGBA values *indexed* from the Colormap with index ``X``."

Comment: @Ffisegydd it may be worth pointing towards the different behaviors depending on whether a float or an integer is passed to the cmap function

Comment: `import matplotlib.cm` also resolved `module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'cm'` as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52255079/6265439

Comment: why is it so damn hard to work with color maps in matplotlib? It's so much easier in Matlab which matplotlib tries to mimic.

Comment: Since this way is getting deprecated, here's an up-to-date one:
`import matplotlib`
`cmap = matplotlib.colormaps["Spectral"]`

Answer (score 24):

In order to get rgba integer value instead of float value, we can do

```
rgba = cmap(0.5,bytes=True)
```

So to simplify the code based on answer from Ffisegydd, the code would be like this:

```
#import colormap
from matplotlib import cm

#normalize item number values to colormap
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1000)

#colormap possible values = viridis, jet, spectral
rgba_color = cm.jet(norm(400),bytes=True) 

#400 is one of value between 0 and 1000
```

Answer (score 14):

I once ran into a similar situation where I needed "n" no. of colors from a colormap so that I can assign each color to my data.
I have compiled a code to this in a package called "[mycolorpy](https://github.com/binodbhttr/mycolorpy)".
You can pip install it using:

```
pip install mycolorpy
```

You can then do:

```
from mycolorpy import colorlist as mcp
import numpy as np
```

Example: To create a list of 5 hex strings from cmap "winter"

```
color1=mcp.gen_color(cmap="winter",n=5)
print(color1)
```

Output:

```
['#0000ff', '#0040df', '#0080bf', '#00c09f', '#00ff80']
```

Another example to generate 16 list of colors from cmap bwr:

```
color2=mcp.gen_color(cmap="bwr",n=16)
print(color2)
```

Output:

```
['#0000ff', '#2222ff', '#4444ff', '#6666ff', '#8888ff', '#aaaaff', '#ccccff', '#eeeeff', '#ffeeee', '#ffcccc', '#ffaaaa', '#ff8888', '#ff6666', '#ff4444', '#ff2222', '#ff0000']
```

There is a [python notebook](https://github.com/binodbhttr/mycolorpy/blob/master/usage_example.ipynb) with usage examples to better visualize this.

Say you want to generate a list of colors from a cmap that is normalized to a given data. You can do that using:

```
a=random.randint(1000, size=(200))
a=np.array(a)
color1=mcp.gen_color_normalized(cmap="seismic",data_arr=a)
plt.scatter(a,a,c=color1)
```

Output:
[image]

You can also reverse the color using:

```
color1=mcp.gen_color_normalized(cmap="seismic",data_arr=a,reverse=True)
plt.scatter(a,a,c=color1)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, while it already has an excellent approved answer. Added to this is that there are already tools out there that do a great job at the performing the process you describe, like CMasher (https://cmasher.readthedocs.io/index.html).

Comment: @1313e: The "excellent approved answer" doesn't work anymore. So there's that. Thanks for the link to this excellent library, though.

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

I had precisely this problem, but I needed sequential plots to have highly contrasting color.  I was also doing plots with a common sub-plot containing reference data, so I wanted the color sequence to be consistently repeatable.

I initially tried simply generating colors randomly, reseeding the RNG before each plot.  This worked OK (commented-out in code below), but could generate nearly indistinguishable colors.  I wanted highly contrasting colors, ideally sampled from a colormap containing all colors.

I could have as many as 31 data series in a single plot, so I chopped the colormap into that many steps.  Then I walked the steps in an order that ensured I wouldn't return to the neighborhood of a given color very soon.

My data is in a highly irregular time series, so I wanted to see the points and the lines, with the point having the 'opposite' color of the line.

Given all the above, it was easiest to generate a dictionary with the relevant parameters for plotting the individual series, then expand it as part of the call.

Here's my code.  Perhaps not pretty, but functional.

```
from matplotlib import cm
cmap = cm.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')  #('hsv') #('nipy_spectral')

max_colors = 31   # Constant, max mumber of series in any plot.  Ideally prime.
color_number = 0  # Variable, incremented for each series.

def restart_colors():
    global color_number
    color_number = 0
    #np.random.seed(1)

def next_color():
    global color_number
    color_number += 1
    #color = tuple(np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.5, 3))
    color = cmap( ((5 * color_number) % max_colors) / max_colors )
    return color

def plot_args():  # Invoked for each plot in a series as: '**(plot_args())'
    mkr = next_color()
    clr = (1 - mkr[0], 1 - mkr[1], 1 - mkr[2], mkr[3])  # Give line inverse of marker color
    return {
        "marker": "o",
        "color": clr,
        "mfc": mkr,
        "mec": mkr,
        "markersize": 0.5,
        "linewidth": 1,
    }
```

My context is JupyterLab and Pandas, so here's sample plot code:

```
restart_colors()  # Repeatable color sequence for every plot

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
plt.title("%s + T-meter"%name)

# Plot reference temperatures:
axs.set_ylabel("°C", rotation=0)
for s in ["T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"]:
    df_tmeter.plot(ax=axs, x="Timestamp", y=s, label="T-meter:%s" % s, **(plot_args()))

# Other series gets their own axis labels
ax2 = axs.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel(units)

for c in df_uptime_sensors:
    df_uptime[df_uptime["UUID"] == c].plot(
        ax=ax2, x="Timestamp", y=units, label="%s - %s" % (units, c), **(plot_args())
    )

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot may not be the best example, but it becomes more relevant when interactively zoomed in.
[image: uptime + T-meter]

Answer (score 1):

To build on the solutions from [Ffisegydd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3005188/ffisegydd) and [amaliammr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3944306/amaliammr), here's an example where we make CSV representation for a custom colormap:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib
import numpy as np 

vmin = 0.1
vmax = 1000

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(np.log10(vmin), np.log10(vmax))
lognum = norm(np.log10([.5, 2., 10, 40, 150,1000]))

cdict = {
    'red':
    (
        (0., 0, 0),
        (lognum[0], 0, 0),
        (lognum[1], 0, 0),
        (lognum[2], 1, 1),
        (lognum[3], 0.8, 0.8),
        (lognum[4], .7, .7),
    (lognum[5], .7, .7)
    ),
    'green':
    (
        (0., .6, .6),
        (lognum[0], 0.8, 0.8),
        (lognum[1], 1, 1),
        (lognum[2], 1, 1),
        (lognum[3], 0, 0),
        (lognum[4], 0, 0),
    (lognum[5], 0, 0)
    ),
    'blue':
    (
        (0., 0, 0),
        (lognum[0], 0, 0),
        (lognum[1], 0, 0),
        (lognum[2], 0, 0),
        (lognum[3], 0, 0),
        (lognum[4], 0, 0),
    (lognum[5], 1, 1)
    )
}


mycmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap', cdict, 256)   
norm = matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin, vmax)
colors = {}
count = 0
step_size = 0.001
for value in np.arange(vmin, vmax+step_size, step_size):
    count += 1
    print("%d/%d %f%%" % (count, vmax*(1./step_size), 100.*count/(vmax*(1./step_size))))
    rgba = mycmap(norm(value), bytes=True)
    color = (rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2])
    if color not in colors.values():
        colors[value] = color

print ("value, red, green, blue")
for value in sorted(colors.keys()):
    rgb = colors[value]
    print("%s, %s, %s, %s" % (value, rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Colormaps come with their own normalize method, so if you have a plot already made you can access the color at a certain value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cmap = plt.cm.viridis

cm = plt.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(10, 10), cmap=cmap)

print(cmap(cm.norm(2.2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found quite short way to return the list of `N` hex colors with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib

# Choose colormap
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('terrain', N)
colors = [matplotlib.colors.to_hex(cmap(i)) for i in range(N)]
```

Hope, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that gives a discrete number of color values. The midpoint can be determined by dividing the discrete color map in half.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

# Choose a colormap from Matplotlib
colormap = plt.cm.viridis

# Set number of colors
num_colors = 5

# Create a ListedColormap with discrete colors
discrete_cmap = ListedColormap(colormap(np.linspace(0, 1, num_colors)))

# Output RGB values
for i, rgb in enumerate(discrete_cmap.colors):
    print(f"Color {i + 1}: RGB = {rgb}")

# Plot a colorbar to visualize
plt.imshow([[i] for i in range(num_colors)], cmap=discrete_cmap, aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(ticks=range(num_colors))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually used is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=10 # number of colors you want to get
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('rainbow', n) # get 10 colors from rainbow palette

# Use the color
cmap(0)
cmap(1)
...
cmap(9)
```

Answer (score -3):

For a quick and dirty you can use the map directly.
Or you can just do what @amaliammr says.

```
data_size = 23   # range 0..23
colors = plt.cm.turbo
color_normal = colours.N/data_size

for i in range(data_size):
    col = colours.colors[int(i*color_normal)]
```