# seaborn heatmap get array of color codes values

Tags: python, colors, heatmap, seaborn

I am trying to get the color codes associated with each cell of a heatmap:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

hm = sns.heatmap(
np.random.randn(10,10),
cmap = cm.coolwarm)

# hm.<some function>[0][0] would return the color code of the cell indexed (0,0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `sns.heatmap` returns a `matplotlib` axis object, we can't really use `hm` directly. But we can use the `cmap` object itself to return the rgba values of the data. **Edit** Code has been updated to include normalization of data.

```
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

data = np.random.randn(10, 10)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('Greens')
hm = sns.heatmap(data, cmap=cmap)

# Normalize data
norm = Normalize(vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())
rgba_values = cmap(norm(data))
```

All of the colors are now contained in `rgba_values`. So to get the color of the upper left square in the heatmap you could simply do

```
In [13]: rgba_values[0,0]
Out[13]: array([ 0.        ,  0.26666668,  0.10588235,  1.        ])
```

For more, check out [Getting individual colors from a color map in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408393/getting-individual-colors-from-a-color-map-in-matplotlib)

---

**Update**

To readjust the colormap from using the `center` and `robust` keywords in the call to `sns.heatmap`, you basically just have to redefine `vmin` and `vmax`. Looking at the relevant seaborn source code (http://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/matrix.py#L202), the below changes to `vmin` and `vmax` should do the trick.

```
data = np.random.randn(10, 10)
center = 2
robust = False
cmap = cm.coolwarm
hm = sns.heatmap(data, cmap=cmap, center=center, robust=robust)

vmin = np.percentile(data, 2) if robust else data.min()
vmax = np.percentile(data, 98) if robust else data.max()
vmin += center
vmax += center

norm = Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
rgba_values = cmap(norm(data))
```

Comment: Thank you lanery. What if I were to use the seaborn options "center" and "robust" to adjust the colormap, is there a way to then use the modified colormap? say for instance: heatmap = sns.heatmap(
np.random.randn(10, 10),
cmap = cm.coolwarm,
center=1,
robust=True)

Comment: You need to add a norm object — as called you are only mapping values in [0–1].

Comment: Also cm.get_cmap('Greens') just returns the cm.Greens object.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of how to do that ?

Comment: @spfraib Check out my updated answer regarding the normalization and adjusting for the use of center and robust.

Comment: @mwaskom 1st comment: Thanks, updated answer to show that. 2nd comment: True. I didn't mean to make it sound as though there was something special about `cm.get_cmap`, but I guess my wording may have implied that, so I changed the wording.

Answer (score 2):

Without any knowledge on the input data and arguments of `heatmap` you can get the colors from the underlying `QuadMesh`, knowing that the heatmap should be the first and only `collection` inside the axes that is returned by `heatmap`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = np.array([[0,-2],[10,5]])
ax = sns.heatmap(data, center=0, cmap="bwr", robust=False)
im = ax.collections[0]
rgba_values = im.cmap(im.norm(im.get_array()))
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794540/4124317). In contrast to `AxesImage`, `QuadMesh` returns a list of colors. Hence the above code will give you a 2D array where the columns are the RGBA color channels. If you need a 3D output with the first two dimensions being the same as the input data you would need to reshape

```
rgba_values = rgba_values.reshape((im._meshHeight, im._meshWidth, 4))
```