# colormap for 3d bar plot in matplotlib applied to every bar

Tags: matplotlib

Does anyone know how to implement easily colormaps to 3d bar plots in matplotlib?

Consider [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html) example, how do I change each bar according to a colormap? For example, short bars should be mainly blue, while taller bars graduate their colors from blue towards the red...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the physical sciences, it's common to want a so-called LEGO plot, which is I think what the original user is going for. Kevin G's answer is good and got me to the final result. Here's a more advanced histogram, for x-y scatter data, colored by height:

```
xAmplitudes = np.random.exponential(10,10000) #your data here
yAmplitudes = np.random.normal(50,10,10000) #your other data here - must be same array length

x = np.array(xAmplitudes)   #turn x,y data into numpy arrays
y = np.array(yAmplitudes)   #useful for regular matplotlib arrays

fig = plt.figure()          #create a canvas, tell matplotlib it's 3d
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#make histogram stuff - set bins - I choose 20x20 because I have a lot of data
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(20,20))
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+xedges[1:], yedges[:-1]+yedges[1:])

xpos = xpos.flatten()/2.
ypos = ypos.flatten()/2.
zpos = np.zeros_like (xpos)

dx = xedges [1] - xedges [0]
dy = yedges [1] - yedges [0]
dz = hist.flatten()

cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet') # Get desired colormap - you can change this!
max_height = np.max(dz)   # get range of colorbars so we can normalize
min_height = np.min(dz)
# scale each z to [0,1], and get their rgb values
rgba = [cmap((k-min_height)/max_height) for k in dz] 

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color=rgba, zsort='average')
plt.title("X vs. Y Amplitudes for ____ Data")
plt.xlabel("My X data source")
plt.ylabel("My Y data source")
plt.savefig("Your_title_goes_here")
plt.show()
```

Note: results will vary depending on how many bins you choose and how much data you use. This code needs you to insert some data or generate a random linear array. Resulting plots are below, with two different perspectives:

[image: Side perspective of a 3d bar plot in matplotLib]
[image: Perspective 2]

Comment: Superb! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great answer! Make sure to import the colormap from matplotlib: `import matplotlib.cm as cm`

Answer (score 3):

So maybe not exactly what you're looking for (perhaps a good starting point for you), but using

[Getting individual colors from a color map in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408393/getting-individual-colors-from-a-color-map-in-matplotlib)

can give varying solid colors for the bars:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm           # import colormap stuff!
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 4
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=4, range=[[0, 4], [0, 4]])

# Construct arrays for the anchor positions of the 16 bars.
# Note: np.meshgrid gives arrays in (ny, nx) so we use 'F' to flatten xpos,
# ypos in column-major order. For numpy >= 1.7, we could instead call meshgrid
# with indexing='ij'.
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1] + 0.25, yedges[:-1] + 0.25)
xpos = xpos.flatten('F')
ypos = ypos.flatten('F')
zpos = np.zeros_like(xpos)

# Construct arrays with the dimensions for the 16 bars.
dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = hist.flatten()

cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet') # Get desired colormap
max_height = np.max(dz)   # get range of colorbars
min_height = np.min(dz)

# scale each z to [0,1], and get their rgb values
rgba = [cmap((k-min_height)/max_height) for k in dz] 

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color=rgba, zsort='average')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Personally, I find that ugly as sin!  But it probably won't look too bad with a sequential colormap - https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Comment: to scale to [0,1] it should be (k-min_height)/(max_height-min_height) instead