# How do parameters 'c' and 'cmap' behave?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot

**For the pyplot.scatter(x,y,s,c....) function ,**

The matplotlib docs states that :

> c : color, sequence, or sequence of color, optional, default: 'b' The
> marker color. Possible values:
>
> A single color format string. A sequence of color specifications of
> length n. A sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap
> and norm. A 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA. Note that c
> should not be a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence because that is
> indistinguishable from an array of values to be colormapped. If you
> want to specify the same RGB or RGBA value for all points, use a 2-D
> array with a single row.

***However i do not understand how i can change the colors of the datapoints as i wish*** .

I have this piece of code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets
import sklearn.linear_model
import matplotlib


%matplotlib inline
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (13.0, 9.0)

# Generate a dataset and plot it
np.random.seed(0)
X, y = sklearn.datasets.make_moons(200, noise=0.55)
print(y)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=y)#, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
```

[image: the output plot]

**How can i change the colours to suppose black and green datapoints if i wish ? or something else ? Also please explain what exactly cmap does .**

*Why my plots are magenta and blue every time i use plt.cm.Spectral ?*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are essentially two option on how to colorize scatter points.

#### 1. External mapping

You may externally map values to color and supply a list/array of those colors to the `scatter`'s `c` argument.

```
z = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])
colors = np.array(["black", "green"])
plt.scatter(x,y, c=colors[z])
```

#### 2. Internal mapping

Apart from explicit colors, one can also supply a list/array of values which should be mapped to colors according to a normalization and a colormap.

- A `colormap` is a callable that takes float values between `0.` and `1.` as input and returns a RGB color.
- A normalization is a callable that takes any number as input and outputs another number, based on some previously set limits. The usual case of `Normalize` would provide a linear mapping of values between `vmin` and `vmax` to the range between `0.` and `1.`.

The natural way to obtain a color from some data is hence to chain the two,

```
cmap = plt.cm.Spectral
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=4, vmax=5)
z = np.array([4,4,5,4,5])
plt.scatter(x,y, c = cmap(norm(z)))
```

Here the value of `4` would be mapped to `0` by the normalzation, and the value of `5` be mapped to `1`, such that the colormap provides the two outmost colors.

This process happens internally in `scatter` if an array of numeric values is provided to `c`.

A `scatter` creates a `PathCollection`, which subclasses `ScalarMappable`. A `ScalarMappable` consists of a colormap, a normalization and an array of values. Hence the above is internalized via

```
plt.scatter(x,y, c=z, norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
```

If the minimum and maximum data are to be used as limits for the normalization, you may leave that argument out.

```
plt.scatter(x,y, c=z, cmap=cmap)
```

This is the reason that the output in the question will always be purple and yellow dots, independent of the values provided to `c`.

Coming back to the requirement of mapping an array of  `0` and `1` to black and green color you may now look at the [colormaps provided by matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html) and look for a colormap which comprises black and green. E.g. the `nipy_spectral` colormap

[image]

Here black is at the start of the colormap and green somewhere in the middle, say at `0.5`. One would hence need to set `vmin` to 0, and `vmax`, such that `vmax*0.5 = 1` (with `1` the value to be mapped to green), i.e. `vmax = 1./0.5 == 2`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x,y = np.random.rand(2,6)
z = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1])

plt.scatter(x,y, c = z, 
            norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=2),
            cmap = "nipy_spectral")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Since there may not always be a colormap with the desired colors available and since it may not be straight forward to obtain the color positions from existing colormaps, an alternative is to create a new colormaps specifically for the desired purpose.

Here we might simply create a colormap of two colors black and green.

```
matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["black", "green"])
```

We would not need any normalization here, because we only have two values and can hence rely on automatic normalization.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np
x,y = np.random.rand(2,6)
z = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1])

plt.scatter(x,y, c = z, cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(["black", "green"]))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First, to set the colors according to the values in `y`, you can do this:

```
color = ['red' if i==0  else 'green' for i in y]
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=color)
```

Now talking about `scatter()` and `cmap`.

ColorMaps are used to provide colors from float values. See [this documentation for reference on colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

[image]

For values between 0 to 1, a color is chosen from these colormaps.

For example:

```
plt.cm.Spectral(0.0)
# (0.6196078431372549, 0.00392156862745098, 0.25882352941176473, 1.0) #<== magenta

plt.cm.Spectral(1.0)
# (0.3686274509803922, 0.30980392156862746, 0.6352941176470588, 1.0) #<== blue

plt.cm.Spectral(1)
# (0.6280661284121491, 0.013302575932333718, 0.26082276047673975, 1.0)
```

Note that the results of 1.0 and 1 are different in above code, because the int and floats are handled differently as mentioned in documentation of [`__call__()` here](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/colors.html#Colormap):

> For floats, X should be in the interval `[0.0, 1.0]` to return the
>   RGBA values `X*100` percent along the Colormap line.
>
> For integers, X should be in the interval `[0, Colormap.N)` to
>   return RGBA values *indexed* from the Colormap with index `X`.

Please look at this answer for more better explanation about colormaps:-

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25408562/3374996

In your y, you have 0 and 1, so the RGBA values shown in above code are used (which are representing two ends of the Spectral colormap).

Now here's how `c` and `cmap` parameters in `plt.scatter()` interact with each other.

```
 _______________________________________________________________________
|No | type of x, y |  c type  | values in c |       result              |
|___|______________|__________|_____________|___________________________|
|1  |   single     |  scalar  |   numbers   | cmap(0.0), no matter      |
|   |    point     |          |             |  what the value in c      |
|___|______________|__________|_____________|___________________________|
|2  |   array of   |  array   |   numbers   | normalize the values in c,|                
|   |    points    |          |             | cmap(normalized val in c) |
|___|______________|__________|_____________|___________________________|
|3  | scalar or    | scalar or| RGBA Values,|  no use of cmap,          |
|   |  array       |  array   |Color Strings|  use colors from c        |
|___|______________|__________|_____________|___________________________|
```

Now once the actual colors are finalized, then cycles through the colors for each point in `x, y`. If the size of x, y is equal to or less than size of colors in c, then you get perfect mapping, or else olders colors are used again.

Here's an example to illustrate this:

```
# Case 1 from above table

# All three points get the same color = plt.cm.Spectral(0)
plt.scatter(x=0.0, y=0.2, c=0, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
plt.scatter(x=0.0, y=0.3, c=1, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
plt.scatter(x=0.0, y=0.4, c=1.0, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)

# Case 2 from above table

# The values in c are normalized 
# highest value in c gets plt.cm.Spectral(1.0)
# lowest value in c gets plt.cm.Spectral(0.0)
# Others in between as per normalizing
# Size of arrays in x, y, and c must match here, else error is thrown
plt.scatter([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 
            c=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)


# Case 3 from above table => No use of cmap here,
#  blue is assigned to the point
plt.scatter(x=0.2, y=0.3, c='b')

# You can also provide rgba tuple
plt.scatter(x=0.2, y=0.4, c=plt.cm.Spectral(0.0))

# Since a single point is present, the first color (green) is given
plt.scatter(x=0.2, y=0.5, c=['g', 'r'])

# Same color 'cyan' is assigned to all values
plt.scatter([0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 
            c='c')

# Colors are cycled through points
# 4th point will get again first color
plt.scatter([0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 
            c=['m', 'y', 'k'])

# Same way for rgba values
# Third point will get first color again
plt.scatter([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 
            c=[plt.cm.Spectral(0.0), plt.cm.Spectral(1.0)])
```

Output:

[image]

Go through the comments in the code and location of points along with the colors to understand thoroughly.

You can also replace the param `c` with `color` in the code of Case 3 and the results will still be same.

Comment: This is partially correct. Even if the OP's `y` array contained different values *within* the interval (0,1), the plot would still show the same outmost colors. This is due to the normalization in use, which always normalizes to the (0,1) interval.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have edited the answer. Please look if this seems correct.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is anything wrong. The part about calling a colormap with an integer is correct, but might be a bit confusing, because colormaps are internally never called without normalization and that would always return float values, i.e. `Spectral(norm(1))` will give the correct rgb value, even if `1` is an integer.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Doesn't `Spectral(norm(1))` give value equal to `Spectral(0.0)`?

Comment: ...depends on the norm of course. But suppose `norm=plt.Normalize(0,1)`, then `Spectral(norm(1)) == Spectral(1.0)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for clarifying. :)