# How to do color code the 3D scatter plot according to time of occurrence in an animated graph?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I have developed a code to create an animated scatter graph.
About the dataset, I have the X,Y,Z coordinate of each point and each event point are assigned a value (M) and each happened at a specific time (t).
I have the size of each point to be proportional to their value (i.e., M), now I want to add the color to each point so that it also shows the time of occurrence. I know I have to use `.set_color(c)` but `c` value expects a tuple value. I tried to normalize the values of the time to map the color from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52115846/13597899). However, there is something that I miss because the code is not working to color the points with related time. I would appreciate it if someone could share their experiences?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML # Animation on jupyter lab 
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter # For GIF animation 
#####Data Generation####

# Space Coordinate
X = np.random.random((100,)) * 255 * 2 - 255
Y = np.random.random((100,)) * 255 * 2 - 255
Z = np.random.random((100,)) * 255 * 2 - 255

# Magnitude of each point
# M = np.random.random((100,))*-1+0.5
M = np.random.randint(1,70, size=100)
# Time
t = np.sort(np.random.random((100,))*10)

#ID each point should be color coded. Moreover, each point belongs to a cluster `ID`
ID = np.sort(np.round([np.random.random((100,))*5]))

x = []
y = []
z = []
m = []

def update_lines(i):
#     for i in range (df_IS["EASTING [m]"].size):
    dx = X[i]
    dy = Y[i]
    dz = Z[i]
    dm = M[i]
#     text.set_text("{:d}: [{:.0f}] Mw[{:.2f}]".format(ID[i], t[i],ID[i]))  # for debugging
    x.append(dx) 
    y.append(dy) 
    z.append(dz)
    m.append(dm)
    graph._offsets3d = (x, y, z)
    graph.set_sizes(m)
    return graph,

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
graph = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, s=M, color='orange')  # s argument here 
text = fig.text(0, 1, "TEXT", va='top')  # for debugging

ax.set_xlim3d(X.min(), X.max())
ax.set_ylim3d(Y.min(), Y.max())
ax.set_zlim3d(Z.min(), Z.max())

# Creating the Animation object
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_lines, frames=100, interval=500, blit=False, repeat=False)
# plt.show()
ani.save('test3Dscatter.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.close()
HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "Color" to "cmap" so that you are able to call set of colors, see below:

```
graph = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, s=M, cmap='jet')  #jet is similar to rainbow
```