# 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'cm' when deploying an app

Tags: python, matplotlib, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app developed using Dash which use some matplotlib functions. When I run locally the application, it runs smoothly and everything is okay, however, when I deploy it using the same code (I'm deploying using heroku) the matplotlib version that is installed (which is the current 2.2.3) no longer find the attrbute 'cm' to create a colormap.

```
import matplotlib
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Reds')
```

**Actual Outcome**

[Logs of the heroku app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3awB.png)

Matplotlib version

I'm using Windows 10, with matplotlib 2.2.3 locally and in the deploy and, locally, my Python version is 3.6.6.

Thank you!

Kind regards,
Renan

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to import `matplotlib.cm` for this to work.

```
import matplotlib.cm
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Reds')
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Reds')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, when I tried to make this a different warning appeared in my app logs: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'