# Getting individual colors from a color scale from colorlover in python

Tags: python, colors, plotly, data-visualization

I have a question similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408393/getting-individual-colors-from-a-color-map-in-matplotlib), but it's for a different library, [colorlover](https://github.com/jackparmer/colorlover).  I would like to create a colorscale and then pull a specific color from that scale.

For example,

```py
    import colorlover as cl
    color_scale = cl.scales['3']['div']['Spectral']
    color_scale
    >['rgb(252,141,89)', 'rgb(255,255,191)', 'rgb(153,213,148)']
```

Then, I'd like to find the color at 75% of the scale with something similar to

```
color_scale(0.75)
```

which would ideally return the rgb value for that color.

I'm also open to using any other package that will return a rgb value or a color format that is compatible with plotly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select a single color from a colorscale and use it in plotly, you can use [matplotlib colormap](http://(0.5273356401384084,%200.8106113033448674,%200.6452133794694349,%201.0)) to select a color, then convert the color to the rgb format that plotly requires.

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408393/getting-individual-colors-from-a-color-map-in-matplotlib),

```py
import matplotlib

#Generate a color scale
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Spectral')

#Select the color 75% of the way through the colorscale   
rgba = cmap(0.75)

#This produces an rgb format between 0 and 1
print(rgba) # (0.5273356401384084, 0.8106113033448674, 0.6452133794694349, 1.0)
```

(If that gives an error, `module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'cm'`, try this instead:)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Spectral')
rgba = cmap(0.75)
print(rgba) # (0.5273356401384084, 0.8106113033448674, 0.6452133794694349, 1.0)
```

We have an RGB color now, but it's in the wrong format for plotly. Plotly requires the format `'rgb(254, 254, 190)'`.  This can be accomplished by multiplying the above elements in the tuple by 255 and then converting to a string.

```py
rgba = tuple(int((255*x)) for x in rgba[0:3])
rgba = 'rgb'+str(rgba)
print(rgba) #'rgb(134, 206, 165)'
```

`rgba` is now a string that can be used to select a color in plotly.