# Group bars with different group sizes in Plotly Express bar plot

Tags: python, plot, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

Consider the following dataframe, called `data`:
[image: dataframe]

Only two elements of the "teacher" column appear twice, the others appear once only.
I make a bar plot with Plotly Express:

```py
import plotly.express as px
px.bar(data.sort_values("start_time", ascending=False), x="teacher", y="start_time", color="start_time",
       color_continuous_scale="Bluered", barmode="group")
```

and the following is output:
[image: output of px bar]

I would like to have bars next to each other, rather than stacked. I think that `px` stacks them (contrary to the behaviour in their docs) because I do not have the same number of occurrences for each teacher.

- Is that correct?
- How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this forum post](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-express-bar-ignores-barmode-group/31511), what is happening is that `plotly.express` is interpreting `start_time` as a continuous variable which is why you get a colorbar, but then falls back onto stacking the bars instead of grouping them.

As suggested by @Emmanuelle, you could solve this by creating a new start_time column that is a string called `start_time_str`, then pass this column to the `color` argument. This forces plotly.express to interpret this variable as discrete. However, you would then lose the color bar and get a legend:

```
data['start_time_str'] = data['start_time'].astype('str')
fig = px.bar(data.sort_values("start_time", ascending=False), x="teacher", y="start_time", color="start_time_str",color_continuous_scale="Bluered", barmode="group")
```

[image]

So assuming you want to preserve the colorbar, and have stacked bars, you'll need a more complicated workaround.

You can use plotly.express to plot the first bar so that you get the colorbar, then use `fig.add_trace` to add the second bar as a `graph_object`. When you add the second bar, you will need to specify the color and to do that, you'll need some helper functions such as `normalize_color_val` that converts the y-value of this bar to a normalized color value relative to the data on a scale of 0 to 1, and  `get_color` which returns the color of the bar (as an rgb string) when you pass the colorscale name and normalized value.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'teacher':['Lingrand','Milanesio','Menin','Malot','Malot','Schminke','Cornelli','Milanesio','Marchello','Menin','Huet'],
    'start_time':[12,12,5,0,5,0,4,8,-1,0,4]}
)

# This function allows you to retrieve colors from a continuous color scale
# by providing the name of the color scale, and the normalized location between 0 and 1
# Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62710057/access-color-from-plotly-color-scale

def get_color(colorscale_name, loc):
    from _plotly_utils.basevalidators import ColorscaleValidator
    # first parameter: Name of the property being validated
    # second parameter: a string, doesn't really matter in our use case
    cv = ColorscaleValidator("colorscale", "")
    # colorscale will be a list of lists: [[loc1, "rgb1"], [loc2, "rgb2"], ...] 
    colorscale = cv.validate_coerce(colorscale_name)
    
    if hasattr(loc, "__iter__"):
        return [get_continuous_color(colorscale, x) for x in loc]
    return get_continuous_color(colorscale, loc)
        

# Identical to Adam's answer
import plotly.colors
from PIL import ImageColor

def get_continuous_color(colorscale, intermed):
    """
    Plotly continuous colorscales assign colors to the range [0, 1]. This function computes the intermediate
    color for any value in that range.

    Plotly doesn't make the colorscales directly accessible in a common format.
    Some are ready to use:
    
        colorscale = plotly.colors.PLOTLY_SCALES["Greens"]

    Others are just swatches that need to be constructed into a colorscale:

        viridis_colors, scale = plotly.colors.convert_colors_to_same_type(plotly.colors.sequential.Viridis)
        colorscale = plotly.colors.make_colorscale(viridis_colors, scale=scale)

    :param colorscale: A plotly continuous colorscale defined with RGB string colors.
    :param intermed: value in the range [0, 1]
    :return: color in rgb string format
    :rtype: str
    """
    if len(colorscale) < 1:
        raise ValueError("colorscale must have at least one color")

    hex_to_rgb = lambda c: "rgb" + str(ImageColor.getcolor(c, "RGB"))

    if intermed <= 0 or len(colorscale) == 1:
        c = colorscale[0][1]
        return c if c[0] != "#" else hex_to_rgb(c)
    if intermed >= 1:
        c = colorscale[-1][1]
        return c if c[0] != "#" else hex_to_rgb(c)

    for cutoff, color in colorscale:
        if intermed > cutoff:
            low_cutoff, low_color = cutoff, color
        else:
            high_cutoff, high_color = cutoff, color
            break

    if (low_color[0] == "#") or (high_color[0] == "#"):
        # some color scale names (such as cividis) returns:
        # [[loc1, "hex1"], [loc2, "hex2"], ...]
        low_color = hex_to_rgb(low_color)
        high_color = hex_to_rgb(high_color)

    return plotly.colors.find_intermediate_color(
        lowcolor=low_color,
        highcolor=high_color,
        intermed=((intermed - low_cutoff) / (high_cutoff - low_cutoff)),
        colortype="rgb",
    )

def normalize_color_val(color_val, data=data):
    return (color_val - min(data.start_time)) / (max(data.start_time - min(data.start_time)))

## add the first bars
fig = px.bar(
    data.sort_values("start_time", ascending=False).loc[~data['teacher'].duplicated()],
    x="teacher", y="start_time", color="start_time",
    color_continuous_scale="Bluered", barmode="group"
)

## add the other bars, these will automatically be grouped
for x,y in data.sort_values("start_time", ascending=False).loc[data['teacher'].duplicated()].itertuples(index=False):
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=[x],
        y=[y],
        marker=dict(color=get_color('Bluered', normalize_color_val(y))),
        hovertemplate="teacher=%{x}<br>start_time=%{y}<extra></extra>",
        showlegend=False
    ))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The second graph is indeed what I want, thanks!. 
I can't believe it is that much work to make such a (seemingly) small change, that's insane

Comment: Yeah, I've encountered issues where you have a colorbar in plotly.express but you need some other feature not available in plotly.express and you'll occasionally have to resort to workarounds like this... glad my answer helped!