# how to convert continuous colorscale into discrete colorscale?

Tags: python, plotly

I'd like to use two colors red and blue but with different concentration like below.
I'd like to convert this continuous color scale into discreate color scale with 10 discreate colors.

https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#reversing-a-builtin-color-scale

If I print the continuous colorscale, it has only 2 element in the list like below. Now How can I get 10 discreate colors between red and blue with different concentrations.  Thanks

```
    colors=px.colors.sequential.Bluered_r
    
    print(colors)

    ['rgb(255,0,0)', 'rgb(0,0,255)']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- really what you are looking at is https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#constructing-a-discrete-or-discontinuous-color-scale
- below code shows how to use a **list comprehension** to construct a discontinuous color scale from a continuous color scale

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({c:np.linspace(1,10,100) for c in list("xyc")})

# https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#constructing-a-discrete-or-discontinuous-color-scale
cmap = [
    (r, c)
    for r, c in zip(
        np.repeat(np.linspace(0, 1, len(px.colors.sequential.RdBu)+1), 2)[1:],
        np.repeat(px.colors.sequential.RdBu,2),
    )
]

px.bar(df, x="x", y="y", color="c", color_continuous_scale=cmap)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**UPD**

There is a simpler way with *sample_colors* from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72633043/18374898)

```
from plotly.express.colors import sample_colorscale
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

colors_ = [1,5,6,7,8] 
discrete_colors = sample_colorscale('Bluered', minmax_scale(colors_))

# colors_ = 5 numbers you are trying to depict with the colorscale
# discrete_colors - list of 5 rgb-coded colors from *Bluered* colorscale
# minmax_scale is used because *sample colors* can only deal with floats from [0,1]
```

**Old answer**

As far as I know, **plotly** doesn't have an explicit function for that.
For a red-blue scale a simple *np.linspace*-based implementation should work.

```
import numpy as np
def n_discrete_rgb_colors(color1: str, color2: str, n_colors: int) -> list:
    color1_ = [int(i) for i in color1[4:-1].split(",")]
    color2_ = [int(i) for i in color2[4:-1].split(",")]
    colors_ = np.linspace(start = color1_, stop = color2_, num = n_colors)
    colors = [str(f"rgb{int(i[0]),int(i[1]),int(i[2])}") for i in colors_]
    return colors

color1, color2 = ['rgb(255,0,0)', 'rgb(0,0,255)']
# color1, color2 = px.colors.sequential.Bluered_r
n_discrete_rgb_colors(color1, color2, 10)
```

Output

```
['rgb(255, 0, 0)',
 'rgb(226, 0, 28)',
 'rgb(198, 0, 56)',
 'rgb(170, 0, 85)',
 'rgb(141, 0, 113)',
 'rgb(113, 0, 141)',
 'rgb(85, 0, 170)',
 'rgb(56, 0, 198)',
 'rgb(28, 0, 226)',
 'rgb(0, 0, 255)']
```

Logic of the code is the following:

1. take two strings for edge colors in `'rgb(x,y,z)'` format,
2. convert them into `[x,y,z]` lists,
3. build a *linspace*,
4. return this linspace with appropriate formatting

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. It works too. I hope I can accept two answers. I appreciate it