# Color line depending on its length with colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to color `lines` with a `colormap` so that the gradient color indicates the length of the `line`. My current program colors `lines`, depending on where they are on the x-axis.

All variables ending with `_2` belong to the diagonal `line`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

x_nom = [0, 1]
y_nom = [0, 1]

# x,y coordinates
x1 = 0
x2 = 0.5
y1 = 0
y2 = 1

x1_2 = 0
x2_2 = 1
y1_2 = 0
y2_2 = 1

# create segments from coordinates
x_coords = np.linspace(x1, x2, 100)
y_coords = np.linspace(y1, y2, 100)

x_coords_2 = np.linspace(x1_2, x2_2, 100)
y_coords_2 = np.linspace(y1_2, y2_2, 100)

# "resolution"
res_ar = np.linspace(x1, x2, len(x_coords))
res_ar_2 = np.linspace(x1_2, x2_2, len(x_coords_2))

# reshape array to fit matplotlib segmentation
points = np.array([x_coords, y_coords]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
points_2 = np.array([x_coords_2, y_coords_2]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
segments_2 = np.concatenate([points_2[:-1], points_2[1:]], axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

# create custom colormap
cvals = [0., 1.]
colors = ['black', 'white']
norm = plt.Normalize(min(cvals), max(cvals))
tuples = list(zip(map(norm, cvals), colors))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', tuples)

# plot segmented line
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc_2 = LineCollection(segments_2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc.set_array((res_ar))
lc_2.set_array((res_ar_2))
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.add_collection(lc_2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, the diagonal `line` is plotted in the full `colormap` (color regions `0 to 1`). It has a `length` of `1.41` (square root of `x=1` and `y=1`). The upper `line` has a length of `1.12` (`x=0.5, y=1`). The upper `line` is about `0.8` times as long as the diagonal `line`. How would I use the `colormap` to color the `line` in region `0 to 0.8` instead of (as of now) `0 to 0.5`?

**Edit:**

Thanks to **tmdavison** I was able to work it out. This code colors the line, depending on its length:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

x_nom = [0, 1]
y_nom = [0, 1]

# x,y coordinates
x1 = 0
x2 = 0.8
y1 = 0
y2 = 1

x1_2 = 0
x2_2 = 1
y1_2 = 0
y2_2 = 1

# create segments from coordinates
x_coords = np.linspace(x1, x2, 100)
y_coords = np.linspace(y1, y2, 100)

x_coords_2 = np.linspace(x1_2, x2_2, 100)
y_coords_2 = np.linspace(y1_2, y2_2, 100)

l_nom = np.sqrt(x_nom[1]**2 + y_nom[1]**2)
l = np.sqrt(x2**2 + y2**2)
correct = l/l_nom

# "resolution"
res_ar = np.linspace(x1, x2, len(x_coords)) * correct/x2
res_ar_2 = np.linspace(x1_2, x2_2, len(x_coords_2))

# reshape array to fit matplotlib segmentation
points = np.array([x_coords, y_coords]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
points_2 = np.array([x_coords_2, y_coords_2]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
segments_2 = np.concatenate([points_2[:-1], points_2[1:]], axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

# create custom colormap
cvals = [0., 1.]
colors = ['black', 'white']
norm = plt.Normalize(min(cvals), max(cvals))
tuples = list(zip(map(norm, cvals), colors))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', tuples)

# plot segmented line
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc_2 = LineCollection(segments_2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc.set_array((res_ar))
lc_2.set_array((res_ar_2))
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.add_collection(lc_2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting individual colors from a color map in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408393/getting-individual-colors-from-a-color-map-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normalise the data array you are using to set the colours by the maximum value it will have. You could do this in two ways:

1. when you construct the `res_ar` and `res_ar_2` arrays

   ```
    res_ar = np.linspace(x1, x2, len(x_coords)) / x2
    res_ar_2 = np.linspace(x1_2, x2_2, len(x_coords_2)) / x2_2
   ```
2. or, when you use those arrays later

   ```
    lc.set_array((res_ar / x2))
    lc_2.set_array((res_ar_2 / x2_2))
   ```

Doing one of those thing will mean the colour scale is always going from 0 to 1.

[image]

Strictly speaking you don't need to do this for you `res_ar` array, since that already goes from 0 to 1, but I added it here to be more general in case that line changed in the future.

Comment: Although your answer does not solve my problem completely, thanks to you I was able to figure it out. Not only was it necessary to add `x2` but also a `correction factor` to `res_ar` that incorporates the `length ratio` of both lines. See the **Edit** section. Anyway, a big thanks :-)